# Why is my custom filter invisible after user profile merge?

Tags: bug, status-completed, merge-accounts, custom-filters

I have merged two user profiles. In one user profile I had created a custom filter named "My C++". Now this filter is not shown anymore. But as soon as I want to create a new custom filter with the same content, I receive an error message, that exactly the same filter already exists.

Also creation of a different filter with the name "My C++" is impossible, because a filter with that name exists already. This feels like a clear bug. Or is there a reason for it? Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: Account merge was always buggy... let's hope Brian can fix that quickly. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I have found a solution: when I create a new, unrelated filter, then the old, hidden filter suddenly appears. Then it is possible to delete or modify it. So the solution is to create a new filter.

Comment: *sigh* For performance reasons, there's a bit on each user that indicates whether or not that have any saved custom filters.  (The fastest cache lookup is no cache lookup.)  Your lists were transferred over but not that bit.  So when you created a second filter it was recalculated to `true` and your list appeared.

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in the next build.

As mentioned in my comment, there's a field on each user profile `HasQuestionLists` which is updated any time a user creates or deletes a filter.  This is used to minimize the number of queries and lookups on page load.  When your profiles were merged, the filters were copied from the removed user to your main user, but the field on the main user wasn't recalculated, so your filters didn't show up until you forced a recalculation by adding another filter.

The merge code was been updated to set the bit if the removed user had any saved filters.